# JPanel not showing background picture when it is scaled

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

im trying to set a background image on a JPanel that resizes with the panel. I have no problem in showing the picture, but as soon as I use:

`background = background.getScaledInstance(300, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );`

nothing is shown. Any ideas on why?

The code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LoginJPanel extends JPanel
{
  private Image background;

  public LoginJPanel()
  {
    super();

    background = new ImageIcon("C:\\ASYS\\Stories\\Authentication UI\\AVDsplashscreen_tiny.jpg").getImage();
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    background = background.getScaledInstance(300, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
         LoginJPanel ip = new LoginJPanel();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame ();
        jf.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        jf.add (ip, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.setSize (1000, 600);
        jf.setLocation (150, 150);
        jf.setVisible (true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: paint methods should be used for only that, painting, dont scale images in there too, move this to your constructor. Not an answer just constructive criticism

Comment: Can you verify that the paint method is completing?  The scale operation may be taking time to complete

Comment: Instead of setting sizes on the `JFrame` what you can do is to override  [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()), and then you can add one [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html), now inside your `componentResized(...)` you can add your `ScaledImage` stuff and then call `repaint()`, for changes to be more practical :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! You are right, I'll move the scaling outside the paintComponent method and see how it works.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I made is (as suggested by the comments) to move the scaling outside the paint method. I created a public method which is called from the parent components to notify the panel about the new size, and scale the picture acording to that:

```
 public void initSize(int _width, int _height)
  {
    int h = background.getHeight(null);
    int w = background.getWidth(null);

    if (w - _width > h - _height)
    {
      scaleVertically(_width, _height);
    }
    else
    {
      scaleHorizontally(_width, _height);
    }
  }
```

I guess I should do this on some listener because this is not very elegant, but I didn't know how to do so.